# Installing Devstack on Baremetal server systemctl fails: devstack@etcd.service is not started

Tags: openstack, devstack

I am trying to install devstack from `./stack.sh` on ubuntu 16.04. The installation fails while trying to start the service `etcd`. I am also unable to run the service manually.

```
devstack@etcd.service - Devstack devstack@etcd.service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/devstack@etcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Sat 2019-04-20 09:01:06 UTC; 8s ago
Process: 28944 ExecStart=/opt/stack/bin/etcd --name scw-priceless-varahamihira --data-dir /opt/stack/data/etcd --initial-cluster-state new -
Main PID: 28944 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 20 09:01:06 scw-priceless-varahamihira systemd[1]: Failed to start Devstack devstack@etcd.service.
Apr 20 09:01:06 scw-priceless-varahamihira systemd[1]: devstack@etcd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 20 09:01:06 scw-priceless-varahamihira systemd[1]: devstack@etcd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 20 09:01:06 scw-priceless-varahamihira systemd[1]: devstack@etcd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 20 09:01:06 scw-priceless-varahamihira systemd[1]: Stopped Devstack devstack@etcd.service.
Apr 20 09:01:06 scw-priceless-varahamihira systemd[1]: devstack@etcd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 20 09:01:06 scw-priceless-varahamihira systemd[1]: Failed to start Devstack devstack@etcd.service.
Apr 20 09:01:06 scw-priceless-varahamihira systemd[1]: devstack@etcd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 20 09:01:06 scw-priceless-varahamihira systemd[1]: devstack@etcd.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the error (`Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'`) is caused by a missing `/var/run/sshd`.

> Run
>
> `mkdir /var/run/sshd`
>
> then
>
> `systemctl restart ssh`
>
> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089310/how-to-resolve-service-start-limit-hit